# Difference between two timestamps in power bi

Tags: powerbi

```
Measure = DATEDIFF(    'machine_jobs'[start_dt],    'machine_jobs'[end_dt],    DAY)
```

> Error : A single value for column 'start_dt' in table 'machine_jobs'
> cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to
> a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation
> such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Measure should be a new column which should have the adjacent difference between start_dt and end_dt in terms of days.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Measure, use a Calculated Column in `machine_jobs` table.

```
Job duration, days = DATEDIFF( [start_dt], [end_dt], DAY)
```

If you want to use a measure then you will need to return a singular value for each column (as the error message says). So try:

```
Measure = DATEDIFF( MIN('machine_jobs'[start_dt]), MAX('machine_jobs'[end_dt]), DAY)
```

Using a measure like this works at the row level context. Meaning, if you wanted a SUM of the diffs you will need to do it by row using `SUMX`, like:

```
Total duration = SUMX('machine_jobs', [Measure])
```

And if you wanted average, then:

```
Avg duration = DIVIDE( [Total duration], COUNTROWS('machine_jobs') )
```

Comment: Job duration, days = DATEDIFF( [start_dt], [end_dt], DAY)

Running this statement, return another error stating : 
The value for 'start_dt' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.

Comment: You need to add the calculated column to the `machine_jobs` table